# cross-platform audio streaming

Tags: linux, windows, raspberry-pi, streaming, nas

I am helping a friend to set up his banana pi (raspberry pi clone) for use as a home server/NAS. At the moment we are trying to set it up to receive and play the audio of any other computer on the lan, mainly running windows. What would be the best way to get this set up?

Comment: Have a look into **DLNA** or UPnP.  There are servers and clients available for most platforms (including linux).  Hopefully they don't all require a GUI to work.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to stream arbitrary live Windows sound output, a commercial solution is Rogue Amoeba's [Airfoil](https://www.rogueamoeba.com/airfoil/) paired with ["Airfoil Speakers for Linux"](https://www.rogueamoeba.com/airfoil/speakers.php).

I don't know of a currently available FOSS solution. (PulseAudio on Windows is defunct.)

Comment: Indeed, we tried pulseaudio without succes.